# Fetch all the user devices from facebook using FbGraph

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I want to get all the user devices from facebook, i am user FbGraph for getting user details. I have fetched the movies, music television, education and some other information successfully, but i am not getting how can i fetch user devices information. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) is documentation link from facebook. Following is the code snippet example how i am getting user information and his interest. I am sure it can be re-factored. **Please tell me how can i fetch all the devices information using FbGraph**. Thanks

```
def self.find_for_facebook(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
  data         = access_token['extra']['user_hash']
  fb_user_data = FbGraph::User.me(access_token['credentials']['token'])

  first_name = data['first_name']
  last_name  = data['last_name']

  # to get the user interests in movies and music i do as follow
  fb_user_data.movies.collect(&:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey all just for information might be helpful for someone else,

i was using `fb_graph 2.6.0` and if you need to fetch all the user devices information you have to upgrade your fb_graph gem to **>=2.6.3**, plus fb_graph depends upon multi_json and it needed **multi_json version >= 1.3** so if some other gem depends on it multi_json version less than 1.3 (you can look in Gemfile.lock file) then there be a conflict between multi_json version you also have to upgrade the other gems too.

After that you can simply fetch the devices as just like any other field as follow,

```
FbGraph::User.me(access_token).devices
```